# AngularJS not recognizing updated input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am practicing AngularJS and JavaScript with jQuery. I am trying my skills my adding my own spin on a tutorial I did about a Saturn Quiz by changing it to a fill-in-the-blank style quiz.

I am able to get the first answer to recognize if it is right or wrong but the next question always returns incorrect even when the answer is right. By using console.log I find that the input value though changed is not recognized by AngularJS.

I even tried to clear the values with a onblur event but it did not work and still retains the previous value when clicking the Check Answer button. I appreciate the help and guidance and I am always looking to improve how I code!

**Edit:** [Here's a link to the Plunkr for a live demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/VJAmxF91ZtFiuWX1qOxm/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="myQuiz" ng-controller="QuizController">
    <h1>Test Your Knowledge:<span>Saturn</span></h1>
    <div class="progress">  
        <div class="{{ ($index === activeQuestion) ? 'on' : 'off' }} 
            {{ (myQuestion.questionState === 'answered') ? 'answered' : 'unanswered' }}
            {{ (myQuestion.correctness === 'correct') ? 'correct' : 'incorrect' }}" 
            ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="intro {{ (activeQuestion > -1) ? 'inactive' : 'active' }}"> 
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <p>Click to begin to test your knowledge of Saturn.</p>
        <p class="btn" ng-click="activeQuestion = 0">Begin</p>
    </div>

    <div class="question
        {{ $index === activeQuestion ? 'active' : 'inactive' }}
        {{ myQuestion.questionState === 'answered' ? 'answered' : 'unanswered' }}" 
        ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
        <p class="txt"> {{ myQuestion.instructions }} </p>
        <div class="txt" ng-bind-html="myQuestion.question | trustAsHtml">
        </div>  

        <p class="ans" 
            ng-class="{  
                correct:isCorrect($index, $index)}"
            ng-click="checkAnswer($index, $index)">Check Answer 
        </p>

        <div class="feedback">
            <p ng-show="myQuestion.correctness === 'correct'"><strong>Correct</strong>.</p>
            <p ng-show="myQuestion.correctness === 'incorrect'">Oops! That is not correct.</p>
            <p> {{ myQuestion.feedback }} </p>
            <div class="btn" ng-click="selectContinue()">Continue</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**App.js**

```
myApp.controller('QuizController', ['$scope', '$http', "$sce", function($scope, $http, $sce){
    $scope.score = 0;
    $scope.activeQuestion = -1;
    $scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0;
    $scope.percentage = 0;

    $http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
        $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
        $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
});

$scope.checkAnswer = function(qIndex,aIndex){
    var questionState = $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState;

        if(questionState != 'answered') {
            var userAnswer = $(".fillin").val();

            var correctAnswer = $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionAnswer;

            $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionAnswer = correctAnswer;

                    if(userAnswer === correctAnswer){
                        $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctness = 'correct';
                        $scope.score += 1;
                        console.log('Correct!' + $scope.score);
                    }
                    else{
                        $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].correctness = 'incorrect';
                        console.log('Wrong!');
                        console.log(correctAnswer); 
                        console.log(userAnswer); //logs previous input submitted
                        console.log( $(".fillin").val() ); //logs previous input submitted even though the value has changed
                    }
                $scope.myQuestions[qIndex].questionState = 'answered';

        }else{
            console.log('Something is wrong');
        }

}

$scope.selectContinue = function(){
    return $scope.activeQuestion += 1;
}

$scope.clearValues = function(){
    $(".fillin").focus(function(){
            $(this).val('');
            console.log('fillin value is ' + userAnswer)
    });
}
```

**data.json**

```
[
    {
        "questionId": 0,
        "question" : "Saturn is <input id='guess-input' class='fillin' ng-blur='clearValues()' type='text' name='\"six\"'> many planets from the sun?",
        "questionAnswer" : "six"
    },
    {
        "questionId": 1,
        "question" : "Around Saturn are <input id='guess-input' class='fillin' ng-blur='clearValues()' type='text' name='\"rings\"'>",
        "questionAnswer" : "rings"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you combine your code using `JavaScript/HTML/CSS` snippet in the editor or write your code on `fiddler` so we have a working example?

Comment: Hi, good suggestion I went ahead and added a working demo on plunkr. Hope this helps!

Comment: you need to add the quiz_data.json in your plunkr

Comment: Sorry about that, I had forked and not saved it properly. I've updated the link, and verified it is correct.

Comment: I'm going to guess and say it's because you are using jq to change the value of the input instead of doing it through an Angular aware context.  Angular doesn't see the change so it doesn't react.  See [anti-patterns](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide%3A-Anti-Patterns).  You should also consider avoiding mixing Angular and jq for this reason or at least use jqlite through the [angular element mechanism](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: as zero said, remove all jQuery commands and solve it in pure angularjs.

Comment: I've removed jQuery entirely and replace the jQuery calls with JavaScript but I have the same problem. Updated plunk: https://embed.plnkr.co/aKBb0CFOr09sbX7CqMat/

Comment: @user5854648 https://plnkr.co/edit/66MaljUI3FSgVvZ2nb7V?p=preview
Mainly converted the question template to exclude the input element and fill in by code.

Comment: @lcycool Your plnkr looks like it's still using jQuery and it also doesn't work...I'm not sure what has changed?